# libigl: How to save mesh along with uv map

Tags: save, libigl

**My question is how to save a mesh along with uv map in libigl.**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  using namespace Eigen;
  using namespace std;

  // Load a mesh in OFF format
  igl::readOFF(TUTORIAL_SHARED_PATH "/camelhead.off", V, F);

  // LSCM parametrization
  igl::lscm(V,F,V_uv);

  // How to save mesh along with uv map
}
```

The writeobj header states the following function for writing obj but it requires surface normals etc. which I dont have.

```
  IGL_INLINE bool writeOBJ(
    const std::string str,
    const Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedV>& V,
    const Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedF>& F,
    const Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedCN>& CN,
    const Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedFN>& FN,
    const Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedTC>& TC,
    const Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedFTC>& FTC);
```

**Is there any way to write the mesh file with just vertices, faces and uv map in libigl?**